# Is there a way to generate pb files based on the options same as loadSync method uses?

Tags: node.js, typescript, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-node

When using dynamic code generation, we can load `.proto` files using:

```js
const packageDefinition: PackageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH, {
  keepCase: true,
  longs: String,
  enums: String,
  defaults: true,
  oneofs: true,
  includeDirs: [__dirname],
});
```

We can set `keepCase` option to preserve field names, don't change them to camel case. And `enums` option, so we can use the string represent of enums.

Now, I am using static code generation. Facing above two problems, here is a method implementation of my service:

```js
  public async getTopics(call: ServerUnaryCall<GetTopicsRequest>, callback: sendUnaryData<GetTopicsResponse>) {
    const obj = call.request.toObject();
    const url = `${config.CNODE_API_URL}/topics`;
    const params = {
      page: obj.page || obj.page + 1,
      tab: (getEnumKeyByEnumValue(Tab, obj.tab) || '').toLowerCase(),
      mdrender: (getEnumKeyByEnumValue(Mdrender, obj.mdrender) || 'true').toLowerCase(),
      limit: obj.limit,
    };
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(url, { params });
      const data = res.data;
      // console.log(data);
      const topicsResponse = new GetTopicsResponse();
      data.data.forEach((po, i) => {
        const topic = new Topic();
        topic.setId(po.id);
        topic.setAuthorId(po.author_id);
        topic.setTab(Tab[po.tab.toUpperCase() as keyof typeof Tab]);
        topic.setContent(po.content);
        topic.setTitle(po.title);
        topic.setLastReplyAt(po.last_reply_at);
        topic.setGood(po.good);
        topic.setTop(po.top);
        topic.setReplyCount(po.reply_count);
        topic.setVisitCount(po.visit_count);
        topic.setCreateAt(po.create_at);
        const author = new UserBase();
        author.setLoginname(po.author.loginname);
        author.setAvatarUrl(po.avatar_url);
        topic.setAuthor(author);
        topicsResponse.addData(topic, i);
      });
      topicsResponse.setSuccess(data.success);
      callback(null, topicsResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      const metadata = new Metadata({ idempotentRequest: true });
      metadata.set('params', JSON.stringify(params));
      metadata.set('url', url);
      const ErrGetTopics: ServiceError = { code: status.INTERNAL, name: 'getTopicsError', message: 'call CNode API failed', metadata };
      callback(ErrGetTopics, null);
    }
  }
```

Here are the problems I am facing:

- Can't set default value when using proto3, want to set default value of  `page` argument to `1`, NOT `0`.
- I need to convert enum from number to string represent manually.
- The fields from RESTful API response is snake case, but `protoc`, `grpc_tools_node_protoc` and `grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts` plugin generate models which have camel case fields. So I want to keep case.
- As you can see, the hydration process is not convenient and boring. I need to call setters to set value for field one by one.